# Modifying permissions on files/items in version control using TFS API

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-sdk

Using the TFS API, I need to change permissions on a specified file/item in version control.  I need to edit permissions for a particular user or for all users.

For instance, my app will prevent check-in of a specified file for all users.  Then, it would allow check-in of that file for a particular user, perform check in of the file, then allow check-in again for all users.

How can I do this?  Please provide example code.

---

Comment: TFS API can be used to accomplish this but I seriously think you are trying to do something that you shouldn't. Can you clarify why you need something like this? Maybe we can come up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

With guidance from Vicky Song at Microsoft (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/289fb1f4-4052-41f1-b2bf-f97cd6d9e389/), here is what I ended up with:

```
public void SetCheckInLockForFile(string fileAndPath, string userGroup, bool checkInLock)
{
  // sets of the CheckIn permission for the specified file

  List<SecurityChange> changes = new List<SecurityChange>();
  string[] perm = new string[] { PermissionChange.ItemPermissionCheckin };

  if (checkInLock)
    changes.Add(new PermissionChange(fileAndPath, userGroup, null, perm, null));
  else
    changes.Add(new PermissionChange(fileAndPath, userGroup, null, null, perm));

  SecurityChange[] actualChanges = versionControlServer.SetPermissions(changes.ToArray());

}
```

When CheckInLock is true, a deny permission is added for check in.  When CheckInLock is false, the check in permission is removed, allowing check in permission for the specified file to be inherited.